# c++ matrix when using intel MKL

Tags: c++, matrix

I am making a C++ code for a mathematic problem using matrix.

Before this, I have used fortran 90/95 to deal with this problem using the default functions and methods for the fortran array, and I found it was very easy and looked like Matlab.

But now in C++, I use VS2015 + Intel Parallel 2017 with intel MKL. I find it is hard to define a dynamic matrix and to use it like matlab and the way by fortran. I have tried Eigen with its MatrixXd and Array, but our boss prefers to just using MKL for commercial and some other reasons probably.
So I don't konw how to deal with this.

Is there any defination for matrix in MKL?

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl/documentation <- start here.

Comment: Some details might be helpful: Are you working with sparse (many 0s) or dense matrices? What are your problem sizes? MKL provides features that are specified by the BLAS and LAPACK interfaces, but especially for sparse matrices, you would probably need to do some work to use these interfaces with your code.

Comment: @TobiasRibizel Thank you for your help. We are dealing with a CFD-like problem. I think the max size of the matrix is about 40*40, and there should be not many 0s. For now, I just use the dot_product, array multi, matrix multi, transpose, slice of the matrix and the LU or QR method for the solution of A*x=b. I find it is very easy to use the two dimensional array a[][] with BLAS and LAPACK, but not very good at the dynamic defination. I tried Eigen, but it was hard when monitor the element in the MatrixXd in the debug mode.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SharpYoung In that case, I would recommend using the [Armadillo library](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) which provides a direct interface to MKL and a dedicated matrix type.

Comment: @TobiasRibizel Thank you very much. I searched this library. It seems like Matlab and easier in writing codes than Eigen. I will try it.

Comment: @TobiasRibizel Sorry to ask you again. I find Armadillo and Eigen both could use the MKL, and Armadillo also could use the OpenBLAS. As our company has bought the Intel Parallel Studio, is it better to use Armadillo+MKL than Armadillo+OpenBLAS or Eigen+MKL?

Comment: @SharpYoung No problem! My guess is that MKL might be a bit faster (at least on Intel CPUs) than OpenBLAS. Whether you use should Armadillo or Eigen depends mostly on your preferences, so if Armadillo looks good to you, just use it ;)

Comment: Both Eigen and Armadillo are easy to debug with Visual Studio.  Both use MKL.  Which is better to use is an opinion question.  Voting to close.

Comment: @TobiasRibizel Thank you very much. I am working with Armadillo+MKL. It's amazing!

Comment: @Matt Thank you again. Now I am trying Armadillo+MKL.